# How to choose where and how long to have my layover

Tags: air-travel, bookings, layovers

I would like to make a stop from the west coast of the United States to NYC, then to Berlin. I may just stop in NYC for a few days, or for up to a week -- I'm really not sure at this moment.

1. Is there any way to choose your flight by where you would want to have a layover and for how long? Is it even considered a layover if its several days?
2. Is there a price difference between doing the above and just booking two separate flights?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For international flights, the magic number is usually (but not always) [24 hours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/when-does-the-24-hour-layover-rule-apply?rq=1).  If your flights are less than 24 hours apart, it's a "transit" or a "layover" and it's free; if it's over 24 hours, it's usually "stopover" and you may need to pay extra.  Note that [these terms are not always used consistently](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/in-the-context-of-air-travel-are-layovers-different-to-stopovers) and it's not always 24 hours; I've seen up to 72 hour (3 day) connections on eg. China Southern, especially if one of the legs is not flown daily, while I gather on US domestic flights the window may be as low as 4 hours.

The problem is that [most online booking websites are really bad at booking stopovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/modifying-online-flights-to-include-stopovers).  If you search for a roundtrip, they only show the "free" connections of less than 24 hours, and if you try to do a multi-city search for LAX-NYC-TXL-LAX, they'll usually do something stupid like add up three rack-rate one-ways and quote you ridiculous prices.

My usual approach is to search for my flights at [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) (toggle "Advanced routing codes" and try eg. `LAX` to `TXL` with `X:NYC` in the outbound routing codes), find a fare where the fare conditions in the small print specifically allow a stopover for a low or zero fee, then take the printout to a travel agent and get them to book it with a stopover added in.  For example, searching for a 14-day trip in March, I can find a $1014 fare on United via Newark (EWR) that appears to allow stopovers.

And yes, this is usually *far* cheaper than booking flights separately.  For example, I had to fly Sydney-Tokyo-San Francisco last year, and three separate flights on the same route (3 one-way flights) would have cost me around 3x more than booking a SYD-SFO roundtrip with a stopover in Tokyo.

Comment: Sorry, I have 3 questions to follow up: When you say to look in the "small print", do I have to manually search through each one and look at the fine print? And do I need to go to a travel agent or could I just book it myself? Lastly, when you say it is cheaper, are you referring to layovers or stopovers or both?

Comment: Yes, manually.  And yes, you'll need to book with an agent or directly with the airline over the phone, it's generally not possible to book stopovers online. And on most "legacy" airlines, *anything* is cheaper than a series of one-ways.