# Flying from Cedar Rapids to New York via Chicago, don't want to miss the sight seeing of downtown Chicago

Tags: luggage-storage, chicago, ord

I will be flying from Cedar Rapids to New York via Chicago and I want to visit Chicago. I searched and found that I can get 9 hours transit by having multiple tickets i.e. CID to ORD then ORD to NYC (since single ticket is offering up to 50 mins transit only). By doing so, I am going to land Chicago at 1300 hrs and fly at 2140 hrs for New York. I assume that I will get my checked baggage also which I can't afford to carry it to down town. what should I do with my checked baggage, is there any facility to deposit your checked baggage at O'Hare?

Comment: You could always check-in early to your next flight, and let the airline deal with your baggage!

Comment: It's often possible to book a single ticket with a longer stopover, but it may not show up on all online searches. If you're on one ticket, your bags will be checked through. ITA Matrix [can do these types of searches](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23829/how-to-choose-where-and-how-long-to-have-my-layover), but you'd have to book elsewhere. [Kayak](https://www.kayak.com) allows you to set filters for layover airport and layover duration. You can also always try calling the airline to see if they can book it for you if you can't price it online.

Comment: And once you did a search on Matrix, you can force it on Hipmunk because Hipmunk understands a few of Matrix's codes most importantly the F code.

Comment: Or, if both flights are with the same airline, the agent in CID may be able to check it through anyway, even on separate tickets.

Answer (score 3):

As of March 2016, [you can't store your luggage at O'Hare:](http://www.flychicago.com/OHare/EN/Connect/FAQs/Frequently-Asked-Questions.aspx#topic3)

> - Can I store luggage at the airport?
>
>   Currently there are no facilities or provision for the storage of luggage at O'Hare International Airport.

Your best bet (as noted by @MichaelHampton in the comments) is probably to give it to the airline for your ORD-NYC flight, and then leave the airport to do your sight-seeing.

---

You didn't ask but I'm telling you anyways:  Your best bet is to take the CTA Blue Line to & from downtown.  Allow 1 hour each way.  Assuming that you want to get back to the airport by about 20:00, and that you won't actually be free of the airport until 14:30 (allowing for travel delays and the time to claim & re-check your bags), you still should have a good 3.5 hours in the downtown area.  If it's a nice day, and you have some money to spare, I highly recommend a [boat tour from the Chicago Architecture Foundation.](https://www.architecture.org/experience-caf/tours/detail/chicago-architecture-foundation-river-cruise-aboard-chicagos-first-lady-cruises/)